# ERROR for jp@gc - Firefox Driver Config

Tags: javascript, webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

[image]

Hi All,

When i run the web page using Jmeter webdriver sampler in my device with (Indian server) I can achieve my task successfully without any issues, but when the same .jmx file is run on another device with (US server) it throws an error (I have attached that error as image format). I am sure that there is no issues in scripting and please let me know, what could I do to over come this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your "US Server" doesn't have WebDriver Set plugin installed. You will need to install [WebDriver Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSet/) on the "US Server" and restart JMeter there to pick up the new libraries.

The fastest and the easiest way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up to date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager), the relevant package is `Selenium/WebDriver Support`

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager WebDriver]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I will make these changes immediately and let you you whether it works or not.